# NReco pdf generator change binary path

Tags: c#, pdf

I want to install the *wkhtmltopdf.exe* in an specific tools folder on the server and use it instead the version decompressed in the bin folder.

This is the line I'm using:

```
var pdfBytes = nRecohtmltoPdfObj.GeneratePdf(strView);
```

How can I change the path where the executable is located?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use PdfToolPath property of converter:

```
var converter = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
converter.PdfToolPath = "your path";
var pdfBytes = converter.GeneratePdf(htmlContent);
```